# Webpack unable to find Pipe decorators

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm in the process of migrating our web app from systemjs and gulp bundling to webpack.  My latest issue is that all of our custom pipes are failing to load.

[image]

The pipes all previously worked.  Is there some Webpack configuration that is required to preserve the pipe decorators?  It is able to resolve the pipe decorators for the Angular defined pipes.  Below is an example of one of our custom pipes.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { StringUtils } from "../../utils/string/string-utils"

@Pipe({name: 'titleCase'})
export class StringTitleCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(input: string): string {
        return StringUtils.titleCase(input);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you need babel to transpile these decorators? guessing.